# Angular 2.0.1 AsyncPipe doesn't work with Rx Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-template, behaviorsubject, subject-observer

AsyncPipe works with BehaviorSubject, but I don't want to initialize my service with empty data, for this reason I use Subject intead.

The problem is NgFor and asyncPipe doesn't work with Subject, is it an issue?

This works:

Component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  foo = new BehaviorSubject<Array<number>>([1,2,3]);

  getFoo(){
     return this.foo.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Template

```
<span *ngFor="let e of foo.asObservable() | async">{{e}}</span>
```

**This NOT WORKS:**

Component

```
export class AppComponent {
  foo = new Subject<Array<number>>();

  constructor(){
     setTimeout(() => {
          this.foo.next([1,2,3]);
     }, 3000);
  }

  getFoo(){
     return this.foo.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Template

```
<span *ngFor="let e of foo.getFoo() | async">{{e}}</span>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle/plunk to replicate the issue?

Comment: See update @estus

Comment: I guess the problem is `.asObservable()`, it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is calling a method from my template - this means every time change detection runs, I'm calling your getFoo() function, which returns a new instance of the observable, which resets the async pipe.

So, the code fails whether you call getFoo() in the NgFor.

Solucion, create an observable variable in the component.

Comment: You're not calling `getFoo()` anywhere in your template.

Comment: Sorry, In the wrong case I created the `getFoo()` but I forgot to call it in the view. I just update it now. Anyway, same behavior cause I was calling `asObservable()`. Thanks.

Comment: could you elaborate on "create an observable variable in the component?"    I have a variable like this `private user: Observable<User>;`  in my component.  But... this didn't work!   Do you have to initialize the observable or something?